# Programming syntax questionin usage of CNTKLibrary from C++

Tags: c++, cntk

This is just a C++ programming syntax question (I think).  I have 192 floats in a structure like:

std::vector outputData(192);

I want to call the built-in Softmax function in the CNTKLibrary on this 192x1 vector -- the documentation in the header file is:

/// Create an instance of the CNTK built-in softmax operation on specified tensor input operand 
CNTK_API FunctionPtr Softmax(const Variable& operand, const std::wstring& name = L"");

How do I do that?  I guess first I get the function pointer, and then I apply it, but I don't understand what the syntax would be.  Something like this...

// Grab Softmax Function pointer

FunctionPtr SoftmaxFuncPtr = Softmax(outputData);   // how to cast arg?

// How to evaluate this FuntionPtr?

SoftmaxFuncPtr->eval();                  // WAG - I have no idea...

Where does result of computation go?

Thanks if you can give me some hints...

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), then make sure your question looks like you intend it to look. Use the preview pane below your editing field.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define a Variable for the input of Softmax, something like:

```
auto inputVar = InputVariable(DimensionsOfInput, DataType::Float, L"InputSoftMax");
```

Then, you build a Composite Function using Softmax, like

```
FunctionPtr SoftmaxFuncPtr = Softmax(inputVar, L"SoftMax"); 
auto EvalFuncPtr = AsComposite(SoftmaxFuncPtr, L"EvalSoftMax");
```

After that , construct input and output map to prepare data for evaluation and then call Forward() or Evaluate() to execute evaluation on the input data and get output result.

The sample MultiThreadsEvaluationWithNewFunction() in [EvalMultithreads.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Evaluation/CNTKLibraryCPPEvalCPUOnlyExamples/EvalMultithreads.cpp) showcases how to create a new function for evaluation. The [page](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Eval-Examples) describes how to use these samples. The function there contains multiple layers and supports evaluation using multi-threads, so it might have some code which is not required for your case. And the sample is still using low-level APIs to manipulate input and output data, and we have also high-level convenient methods, like Value::CreateBatch/Sequence/BatchOfSequence(), Value::CopyVariableValueTo() to help you prepare input/output data without knowing low-level details. The CNTKLibrary.h has description of these APIS too.

Please let us know any questions you have. 
Thanks,

Comment: Hmmm... OK, I'm trying to figure out all the syntax and meaning.... its seems complicated because CNTK is all set up to allow arbitrary tensors, etc.   I'd really like to just make a call like this:
std:vector<float> answer = softmax(outputData);
but it seems like I need to do something like (see next post)...

Comment: // define an input variable
 NDShape DimensionsOfInput(1, ntot);
 auto inputVar = InputVariable(DimensionsOfInput, DataType::Float, L"InputSoftMax");
 std::vector<float> inputData(inputVar.Shape().TotalSize());

 // fill the input variable with data
 for (i = 0; i < ntot; i++)
 {
  inputData[i] = theApp.pNetworkOutput->GetAt(i);
 }

 // build composite function
 FunctionPtr SoftmaxFuncPtr = Softmax(inputVar, L"SoftMax");
 auto EvalFuncPtr = AsComposite(SoftmaxFuncPtr, L"EvalSoftMax");

 ...continued...

Comment: // create input ValuePtr
 ValuePtr inputValue = MakeSharedObject<Value>(MakeSharedObject<NDArrayView>(inputVar.Shape(), inputData, true));  // do I need 'SharedObject" ?


 // create output ValuePtr
 ValuePtr outputValue;
 auto outputVar = EvalFuncPtr->Output();
 std::unordered_map<Variable, ValuePtr> outputs = { {outputVar, outputValue} };

 // apply the function
 EvalFuncPtr->Forward({ { inputVar, inputValue } }, outputs);

 // get the output value
 outputValue = outputs[outputVar];

 // do something else to extract outputData array from the outputValue

Comment: Another reason for providing data mapping is that a Function can have multiple inputs (Softmax has only one), so it is required to specify which data is mapped to which varaible. And the API supports to evaluate batch data, sequence data, or batch of sequence, so the caller needs to specify how to handle its data. The methods CreateBatch(), CreateSequence() and CreateBatchOfSequence() are provided to help users to create different types of input Values from the input plain data. WIth these methods, you can avoid to deal with NDArrayView and other low-level types.

Comment: You can find examples using these methods in C# here (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Evaluation/CNTKLibraryCSEvalCPUOnlyExamples/CNTKLibraryCSEvalExamples.cs). The usage is very similar in C++ (we hope to provide examples using these methods in C++ soon). Please let us know if you have any suggestions to improve the API. Thank you!